# How to remove focus from a mat-form-field - mat-select?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using Angular material for a drop down view. Here is my HTML:

```html
    <mat-form-field class="vertical-center" subscriptSizing="dynamic" #myFormField>
      <mat-label>Style</mat-label>
      <mat-select [ngModel]="selectedStyle" name="styles" (ngModelChange)="onStyleChange($event)">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let style of styles; ">
          <mat-option [value]="style.value">{{ style.viewValue }}</mat-option>
        </ng-container>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

How can I remove the focus during the `(ngModelChange)="onStyleChange($event)"` event?

I tried the below options with no success

1. Directly Blur the mat-select Element
2. Focus on Another Element
3. Trigger a Click on a Different Element
4. Using Angular Focus Trap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `close` function of `mat-select` seems to remove the focus!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatSelect, MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <mat-form-field class="vertical-center" subscriptSizing="dynamic" #myFormField>
      <mat-label>Style</mat-label>
      <mat-select #matSelect [ngModel]="selectedStyle" name="styles" (ngModelChange)="onStyleChange($event, matSelect)">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let style of styles; ">
          <mat-option [value]="style.value">{{ style.viewValue }}</mat-option>
        </ng-container>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  `,
  imports: [MatFormFieldModule, MatSelectModule, FormsModule, CommonModule],
})
export class App {
  selectedStyle = null;
  styles = [
    { value: 'test1', viewValue: 'Test1' },
    { value: 'test2', viewValue: 'Test2' },
    { value: 'test3', viewValue: 'Test3' },
    { value: 'test4', viewValue: 'Test4' },
  ];

  onStyleChange(event: any, matSelect: MatSelect) {
    this.selectedStyle = event;
    matSelect.close();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideAnimations()],
});
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rxkqjy)